Using a toaster oven to slow cook meat
I used to make beef brisket using my regular oven and it came out pretty juicy and soft.  I usually go 250F for 4-5 hours.  The thing I don't like is the high electric bill esp with the rate in my area.  Would a toaster oven be able to replicate the oven in this case and make a soft brisket if I use the same time and temp setting?  The one I'm thinking to get.


Toaster ovens typically have much larger temperature swings than regular ovens. Don't know if that makes a difference...

An "air fryer" is basically a small fan oven, so perhaps that would be a better option for you than using a full-size oven. Air fryers typically cook smaller portions of food to the same, or better, result than a full-size oven in less time and at a lower temperature. So, both a time and money saver :)

If your goal is to save on electricity I would expect this to fail. First, both a regular oven and a toaster oven will transform almost all the electricity you feed into them into heat. The key question is where the heat goes.
You want the heat to go into your food. To get your brisket cooked requires a fixed amount of heat in the food regardless of the type of oven. But of course not all the heat goes into the food.
Part of it will heat the air inside the oven/ toaster oven. For that the toaster oven is better because it is much smaller. However, air is a gas, hence weighs almost nothing compared to the food and only takes a trivial amount of energy to heat. The important heat loss is from heating the oven/ toaster oven itself and from there leaking heat into your kitchen. As a toaster oven is much smaller it is much less efficient than a big oven and will leak a much higher proportion of the total energy into your kitchen.
In summary, for a dish like a beef brisket I would expect it is in general possible to cook it in a toaster oven but it will take much longer than in a regular oven and because of that consume considerably more energy in total until it is done.
A toaster oven will save you energy for small dishes that only require a little bit of heating. Dishing that are big and take a lot of energy/ time to properly cook will require less energy to cook in a big oven.

Im just looking at it from a watt perspective a toaster uses around 1200w while my oven should use around 3000w.  So are you saying the oven uses less watt after it gets to temp?  but I think it would still uses more watts but how much?

@Lightsout Per time the big oven needs more energy than the toaster oven but the toaster oven will take much longer to cook a big piece of meat. With random numbers, 4 hours at 3000 Watt is less total energy than 20 hours at 1200 Watt.

An oven is an oven.  As long as it holds the desired temperature, has enough space, and doesn't have an auto shut off that will not allow it to cook for the desired time, it will work like your large oven.

Are "air fryers" a thing in the USA yet, as opposed to toaster ovens?

They are a thing...I would say not the right tool in this case. One would not need the forced air in a low and slow situation. The line of "toaster ovens" has also expanded to include what are now called counter top ovens.  But again, an oven is an oven.

I used to have a nuwave oven kind of like airfryer but dotn think it worked as well for meats

Question is how well will this little box hold the temperature compared to a full-size oven. After all, the OP's goal is to reduce energy usage.

@DanMašek just one example in the link below.  I would say it is likely that a toaster oven is less costly to run than an full size:https://www.siliconvalleypower.com/residents/save-energy/appliance-energy-use-chart

It's possible, although my intuition would go the other way. (But I'm not gonna go measure it, which is the only way to really find out) The numbers on that page seem way to generalized to make a meaningful comparison for "250 F for 4-5 hours". That doesn't seem like "average operation conditions" for a toaster oven, whatever those are anyway. And for normal oven, I'd expect a fairly wide range of energy usage, given on how it's configured.

@DanMašek we cant be specific without identifying the actual products, but electric ovens in general use almost twice the amount of energy per hour than toaster ovens.  Again, a gross generalization, as there are, of course, all sorts of electric ovens, and all types and sizes of toaster over/counter top oven.  I don't think the OP's theory is wrong here.
